Identify ids with 12 months continuous dates in Oracle
I have a table with data similar to the below. I want to apply an indicator to an id when the dates in the date column are continuous. For example, if an id has dates from 1/2021 to 3/2021 and 6/2021 to 6/2022, then I want the count for the 12 months otherwise I want it to equal 0.
Here is my code:
SELECT DISTINCT id,
COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(date,'MONTH'))
OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS Continuous_Month_Count
FROM Table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '01-JAN-2021' AND '31-DEC-2022'
Expected table:

Dataset:


@Paul W: If I understand this correctly, it is the maximum number of adjacent months - or 0 when that number is lower then 12.

Please don't post images of data or results (or code). It would be helpful to include the DDL and DML to recreate your data, so we don't have to type it in or generate something similar enough to recreate your problem. Also what do you want to see if an ID as more than one run of contiguous months - both counts, the highest, something else?

@Paul W: 2021-06 to 2022-06 are 13 months.

This is called a gaps and islands problem. I am doing this step by step here:

Get distinct months per ID creating adjacent month numbers called mon on the way, so mon(2021-12) + 1 = mon(2022-01).
Get groups of adjacent months per ID and create a group number called grp for this.
Count the months per ID and group.
Get the highest number of months per ID.

The query:
with
  months as
  (
    select distinct id, extract(year from dt) * 12 + extract(month from dt) as mon
    from mytable
  ),
  groups as
  (
    select id, mon - row_number() over (partition by id order by mon) as grp
    from months
  ),
  counted as
  (
    select id, grp, count(*) as num
    from groups
    group by id, grp
  )
select id, case when max(num) < 12 then 0 else max(num) end as continuous_months
from counted
group by id
order by id;


Can this code be edited to be to show the 12 month count based on service dates in another table? For example, if ID 222222 had a service date of 1/15/2022 then 12 months they because they had 12 months either before, after or within date of service date.

Well, if ID 222222 has a 12+ month range, it will of course be "before, after or within date of service date", because when else?! Or do you mean you only want to look at ranges for only one of these options, say show the maximum range per ID before the service date only for instance? Or maybe you want to know where the maximum range resides in regards to the service date? (In that case: there may be several maximum-length ranges, some before, some after, for example.)

I suggest you just try what you want to to, and if you get stuck, open a new request for that.

My apologies, I am looking to identify if there was membership within 12 months of the service date. For Example: if there was membership from 2/15/2021 to 2/15/2022 and the service date is 2/18/2021, then this would count as 12 mos of membership. Here is how I updated the code.

WITH MONTHS_DT AS
( SELECT DISTINCT MEMBER_NBR,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MEMBERSHIP_DATE)*12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MEMBERSHIP_DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE)12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE) AS MOS
FROM MEMBER_MBRSHIP_T1
),
GROUPS AS
(SELECT MEMBER_NBR, MOS-ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MEMBER_NBR ORDER BY MOS) AS GRP
FROM MONTHS_DT
),
COUNTED AS
(SELECT MEMBER_NBR, GRP, COUNT() AS NUM
FROM GROUPS
GROUP BY MEMBER_NBR, GRP
)
SELECT MEMBER_NBR,
CASE WHEN MAX(NUM)<12 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CONTINUOUS_MONTHS
FROM COUNTED

Another way to do this, at least since Oracle 12c, is with match_recognize:
select id,
  case when max(cont_months) >= 12 then max(cont_months) else 0 end as cont_months
from (
  select distinct id, trunc(dt, 'MM') as month_year
  from table1
)
match_recognize (
  partition by id
  order by month_year
  measures
    count(*) as cont_months
  one row per match
  pattern (m n*)
  define 
    n as (month_year = prev(month_year) + interval '1' month)
)
group by id




ID
CONT_MONTHS




111111
0


222222
13



fiddle
This is using an inline view to get the distinct year/month values, the match_recognize is finding patterns where months are contiguous, and counting those. You can then filter on that count being >= 12, or use a case expression to find either the highest >= 12 or zero as I have here, to match your expected result - at least assuming you only want to see the highest number of contiguous months, if there is more than one run of 12+.
